# How to obtain the most recent value from Cloudwatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've written a lambda function to create a custom CloudWatch Metric to display alarm states and it works as intended. I just assign a numerical value to the alarm state i.e. OK = 0 and IN ALARM = 1.

The problem arises when I try to display these values, as querying or searching the metrics require an aggregate function: SUM, AVG, MIN etc. All I'm interested in is the most recent value of the metric since that correlates to the most current state of the alarm.

Is there a way to bypass or negate the aggregate function and just return the most recent value? I've tried different metric math expressions and using the LAST function but it appears to take the last value after already applying the aggregate function which is not what I need.

Comment: No. It is not possible to retrieve individual metric values. They must be accessed via functions. You might be able to use MAX over the previous 1 minute to determine whether it is in ALARM state.